# how to change color a sub ul li - jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a `ul li` tires that make by programmatically as a tree .

for example :

```
<ul style="cursor:pointer" class="change_select">
    <li id="1" class="change_select">A
        <ul style="cursor: pointer; color: rgb(233, 170, 158);" class="change_select">
            <li id="2" class="change_select">B
                <ul style="cursor: pointer; color: rgb(233, 170, 158);" class="change_select">
                    <li id="3" class="change_select">C</li>
                    <li id="4" class="change_select">D</li>
                    <li id="5" class="change_select">E
                        <ul style="cursor: pointer; color: rgb(233, 170, 158);" class="change_select">
                            <li id="6" class="change_select">F</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

it does make this view:

```
A
  B
    C
    D
    E
      F
```

now, I want when user click on `A`, `A` and all sub-trees will change color, when user click `B`, all sub-trees will change color : `B,C,D,E,`F.

my code:

```
    $('.change_select').click(function() {
        changeColorSubCategories(this,this.id);
    });
```

---

```
function changeColorSubCategories(_this,id) {
    console.log(id);
    $(_this).children().css('color','#e9aa9e');
```

but it changes all li's and ul's.
    }

Comment: `id`s should not start with a number, and your parent elements will be triggered every time a sub-elements is

Comment: Like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/7jr8rn90/

Comment: @adeneo please post your answer.